# How do I figure out what module is loading Moose?

Tags: perl, moose, dbix-class

I am trying to figure out which module in my CGI::Application is loading Moose. I attempted to overload "require" but I don't seem to have the syntax quite right. If someone could clean up the following code I would appreciate it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp qw//;

BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::require = sub (*) { 
    warn "Requiring $_[0] at: " . Carp::longmess();
    CORE::require (@_);
  };
}
```

Basically, the problem with this script is that it isn't actually loading anything. When CORE::require(@*) is called is doesn't "do" anything. I tried just passing it the script name directly using $*[0], but that just resulted in the script deadlocking until it timed out.

**NOTE:** The above script is at the beginning of my start up script

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hows about:

```
BEGIN {
  unshift @INC, sub {
    printf "Moose first called by pkg %s at line %d in %s\n", (caller)[0,2,1]
      if $_[1] eq 'Moose.pm';
  };
}
```

This "works" because subroutine references in `@INC` are called and passed the coderef and filename as arguments.  See [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) perldoc:

As mentioned by [phaylon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144633/phaylon), you can also use [Devel::TraceLoad](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::TraceLoad) to get a summary of all modules loaded while your application ran (and what line of what file loaded them) with

```
perl -MDevel::TraceLoad=summary my_progam.pl
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  I like this one particularly because you avoid patching Moose.pm in any way.  Instead you take advantage of a rarely used, but very cool feature of `@INC`.

Comment: If you put that inside an import method into a 'wholoads.pm' and check against the first argument to the method you could use it as 'perl -Mwholoads=Moose yourscript.pl'. I'd also consider using Carp::cluck() to get at stacktraces, since this would also cover lazy-loading modules at runtime.

Comment: @phaylon: Great idea.  Though I wouldn't be surprised if there was a module that already did all this on CPAN?  If not it sounds like a new project!

Comment: @draegtun: After some more searching, there's Devel-TraceLoad which seems quite suitable. It doesn't look for a specific package, but gives a summary.

Comment: @draegtun, great answer. I ended up using Devel-TraceLoad that did the trick, but I like the idea with @INC so I might try that out when I have some more time.

Comment: You're very welcome.  I see that `Devel::TraceLoad` does wrap `require` so definitely room for playing with a @INC solution. PS. phaylon++ for good CPAN search foo!

Comment: We need to know  loading order engineering.

Answer (score 5):

You can find out who is loading a particular module, by inserting a few lines at the start of the module to get the "caller".  Find Moose.pm in your library tree (`perl -mMoose -wle'print $INC{"Moose.pm"}'`, and edit it to:

```
package Moose;

use Data::Dumper;
warn "!!! Moose is being loaded by: ", Dumper([caller]);
```

This is quick and dirty, but it sounds like it's all you need. (Don't forget to unedit the changes to Moose.pm when you are done!)

Answer (score 4):

In *Nix:

```
mkdir dummy
echo > dummy/Moose.pm
perl -I./dummy /path/to/my_script.pl
```

The concept would be the same in Windows.

You should get:

```
Moose.pm did not return a true value at ...
```